# Weak convergence of sums of inner products

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

My problem is the following; suppose $H$ an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space, with orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Define $f_N:=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N^2}{e_n},$ for all $N\geq1.$ Show $f_N\rightarrow0$ weakly.

My previous attempts have gone through use of the triangle inequality and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, yielding a non-useful bound tending to infinity with $N,$ through something along the lines of taking arbitrary $x\in H$ and saying

$\sum_{n=1}^{N^2}{\langle e_n,x\rangle}\leq|\sum_{n=1}^{N^2}{\langle e_n,x\rangle}|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{N^2}{|\langle e_n,x\rangle|}\leq\sum_{n=1}^{N^2}{||e_n||||x||}=N^2||x||,$

such that we may conclude $\langle f_N, x\rangle=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N^2}{\langle e_n,x\rangle}\leq\frac{1}{N}N^2||x||=N||x||\rightarrow\infty,$ as $N\rightarrow\infty.$

What am I missing? - and would the use of $e_n\overset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow}0$ weakly together with $\frac{1}{N}\overset{N\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow}0,$ in any way be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in H$ and $\epsilon >0$. Since $\sum_j |\langle x, e_j \rangle|^{2} <\infty$ there exist $k$ such that $\sum\limits_{j=k}^{\infty} |\langle x, e_j \rangle|^{2} <\epsilon$.  Now $\frac 1 N \sum\limits_{j=1}^{N^{2}} |\langle x, e_j \rangle| \leq \frac 1 N\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k-1} |\langle x, e_j \rangle|+\frac 1 N\sum\limits_{j=k}^{N^{2}} |\langle x, e_j \rangle|$ and $\sum\limits_{j=k}^{N^{2}} |\langle x, e_j \rangle| \leq (\sum\limits_{j=k}^{N^{2}} |\langle x, e_j \rangle|^{2})^{1/2} (N^{2}-k+1)^{1/2}$ by C-S inequality. Can you finish?